# my ionic app does not appear in the safari debug and others ionic apps ,yes

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm not sure what happened. but they lent me an iphone, they send me the link of the .ipa and I install it. the app is a IONIC 3 project.

Currently on my iphone I have an older version of a app installed, I connect the cell phone to my pc and it appears on the safari debug. but for the most recent application of the app, when I connect my cell phone to the pc and run the app, it does not appear. I uninstalled the older version and I kept the new one but I do not know why it does not appear. it simply appears in the safari menu:

```
developer/iphone of (name)
```

but the index or something similar does not appear to be able to inspect. What I can do?

[image]

Comment: When you say you have the new version on your phone, how did you install that new version? Did you build directly to that phone through XCode, or did you copy across an .IPA file in iTunes?

Comment: @ObsidianAge someone compiles the code and passes it to me in .ipa format and then I install it.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has moved to WKWebView as default webview for iOS following Apple's direction:

- [Apple's context](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview?changes=_8)
- [Ionic's context](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/)

This change broke a few things, which are getting gradually patched up.

So since certain version of Safari (~around iOS 11 release) unfortunately ability to debug via dev tools in browser for Ionic 3 apps was broken.

This should be fixed soon.

Try using latest Safari technological preview and it may already be fixed in there.

Comment: but ... how is it explained that a previous version of the app can be debugged and the other can not? (it's the same code and libraries, but with changes) I downloaded "Safari Technology Preview for macOS High Sierra" but my device did not appear..

Comment: Can you share package.json from both?

Comment: I do not have how to do it ... I only have the .ipa

Comment: So then you dont really know which dependencies were part of each build:/ some of those can have very drastic impact. Especially if we talk about 2 year delta